# Error: Incompatibile SockJS! Main site uses: "1.4.0", the iframe: "1.0.0"

Tags: spring-boot, firefox, spring-websocket, sockjs

I am using Spring boot websocket backend.
And React as a frontend.
I have a websocket call which works fine on Chrome but not on Firefox.
Can someone please help?

Below is the error I am getting on the web console.

Error: Incompatibile SockJS! Main site uses: "1.4.0", the iframe: "1.0.0".

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem. It turned to be the connection from browser to server took too much time, therefore sockjs-client tried to downgrade from websocket to http streaming.

My client is Angular, not React. I increased the timeout setting when initiating SockJS in angular resolved my problem:

```
const socket = new SockJS(ENVIRONMENT.api.ws, null, { timeout: 15000});
```